# array inside array

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

There is an array of values from the checkbox. It needs to be sent together with additional value. In php i am getting this:

```
> Array (
>     [0] => [object Object]
>     [1] => value )
```

My code is:

```
$.post('index.php', {'info[]': 
[$("input[name='site_select_[]']:checked"),
$(this).val()]}, function(data){data});
```

Comment: you will have to loop through $("input[name='site_select_[]']:checked") as its an object

Comment: Why not send `info` as an array? Set it up prior to your `$.post` call.

Answer (score 1):

when JavaScript tries to stringify your JQuery object `$("input[name='site_select_[]']:checked")` it only gets "object Object"
I think you have to create a custom object that can be stringified better way.

Answer (score 1):

Let's break down what you send via POST:

```
 {'info[]': [$("input[name='site_select_[]']:checked"), $(this).val()]}
```

which is equivalent to:

```
 {
   'info[]': [
                $("input[name='site_select_[]']:checked"), 
                $(this).val()
             ]
 }
```

So you are sending an Object translated into a PHP Array of a single key/value pair:

```
 {
    'key' : 'value'
 }
```

The key is

```
  info[]
```

So PHP evaluates to `$result = array("info[]", $value);`

And the value is

```
  [
      $("input[name='site_select_[]']:checked"), 
      $(this).val()
  ]
```

Which in turn is a Javascript array of two value, the first is a JQuery object:

```
  $("input[name='site_select_[]']:checked")
```

And the second a "value" of some `this` object, which is NOT the one referred above:

```
  $(this).val()
```

so in PHP you'll have

```
  $result = array("info[]", array(..Jquery object..., jqueryvalue);
```

So I think you have some misunderstanding about the very basics of Javascript and JQuery.

It's is clear that it doesn't work this way; you pass useless data and in a bad way too, and `this` keyword is out of context. Refer to the other answers for reliable solutions.

Comment: Yes, currently I  studying Ajax and i need to send all the data in php

Answer (score 0):

Don't use info[], use info:

```
$.post(
    'index.php',
    {
        info: [$("input[name='site_select_[]']:checked"), $(this).val()]
    },
    function(data){...}
);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this might work

```
{info: 
    $.merge($("input[name=*site_select_]:checked").serializeArray(), 
    [$(this).val()])
}
```

It serialises the objects gotten by the selector `checked` into an array and then you use `merge` to put them together.

I am not sure how this will work since I have not tested it but since this is a "learning" exercise I think you can find that one out.

Warning: Written very quickly.